# ASP WEB API multiple DBContext

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-webapi

I have app asp.net core web api app with 2 controllers
OracleController.cs

```
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        public class OracleController : Controller
        {
            private readonly OracleDbContext _db;  
            public HeatsController(OracleDbContext context)
            {
                _db = context;
            }
            ...
            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _db.Dispose();
                }
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }
    }
```

SqlServerController.cs

```
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        public class SqlServerController: Controller
        {
            private readonly SqlServerDbContext _db;  
            public HeatsController(SqlServerDbContext context)
            {
                _db = context;
            }
            ...
            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _db.Dispose();
                }
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped(_ => new OracleDbContext(Configuration["Data:OracleConnectionString"]));
            services.AddScoped(_ => new SqlServerDbContext(Configuration["Data:SqlServerConnectionString"]));
        }
```

SqlServerDBContext.cs

```
public class SqlServerConfig : DbConfiguration
    {
        public SqlServerConfig()
        {
            SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlClient",
             System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance);
        }
    }

    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(SqlServerConfig))]
    public class SqlServerDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public SqlServerDbContext()
            : base("name=SqlServerDbContext")
        {
        }

        public SqlServerDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        {
        }

        ...

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

After app starts I can access only one DBContext. For example if I call some method from OracleController it works fine but methods from SqlServerController dont work they throw exception " The supplied SqlConnection does not specify an initial catalog or AttachDBFileName.". It works in the same way if i call methods from SqlServerController first.

Comment: Have you a base DbContext for your db contexts ? I mean a parent class.

Comment: Both inherit from DbContext;
public class OracleDbContext : DbContext
    { ... }

Comment: OK, you don't have a custom parent class. I think you need to review your ConfigureServices method, I have this for configuring Sql Server DbContext: services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<AdventureWorksDbContext>();

Comment: I's works with EF 7 (core), but I use EF 6. I can't clearly understand what do you mean

Comment: In EF6 you need to set providerName in web.config file for each connection string, have you ckecked them ?

Comment: Can you show the DbContexts classes' definitions?

Comment: I've updated question

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the error message you are missing `InitialCatalog` property in your connection string. This is required to specify to which database EntityFramework should connect and launch queries against.

Comment: I have InitialCatalog in my connection string

Comment: Could you show me the connection string that you are using?

Comment: data source=****;initial catalog=****;user id=****;password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;

Comment: Do you use the same connection string for both databases?

Comment: No, I use different connection strings